# displaying multiple child components in a parent component on condition

Tags: angular, angular5, angular6, angular7

I am working in Angular 7 Application where

Goal:-

My goal is to display **more then one child components in parent component** in such a way that **only one child component is displayed at a time** and next child component displays after clicking on previous child component

example :-

```
<parent component>
    <h1>dummy text</h1>
    <child component1 *ngIf='c1' (click)='displayc2()'> </child component1>
    <child component2 *ngIf='c2'> </child component2> 
    <child component3 *ngIf='c3'> </child component3>
    <child component4 *ngIf='c4'> </child component4>
<parent component>
```

My way of doing it

Here only child component1 is displayed when page will load so I took

```
c1 = true;
c2 = false;
c3 = false;
c4 = false;
```

and on clicking component child 1 component I am calling function

```
displayc2() {
    this.c2 = true;
    this.c1 = false;

    this.c3 = false;
    this.c4 = false;
}
```

So here I have to write new function again and again to define condition true for displaying each child component.

I am sure there is far better way 
        this is a very tedious and boring way on solving this type of problem , so please **correct me or suggest a better way to solve the problem**

Comment: what you want one component at a time or sequentially show next element

Answer (score 1):

I won't criticize or ask you why you're doing it this way, but there are more suited solutions to your issue.

Other than that, consider using a counter :

```html
<parent component>
  <h1>dummy text</h1>
  <ng-container *ngFor="let i of [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]">
    <child 
      [componentNumber]="i"
      *ngIf="i === counter"
      (click)="counter = counter + 1"></child component2> 
  </ng-container>
<parent component>
```

With this, your code gets simplified, and more importantly, totally dynamic. You can create 600 components, all you have to do is change the array inside `ngFor` !

Comment: forget it, sorry, I delete the comment

Answer (score 0):

```
<parent component>
 <h1>dummy text</h1>
 <child component1 *ngIf='c1 === 1' (click)='c1 = 2'> </child component1>
 <child component2 *ngIf='c1 === 2' (click)='c1 = 3'> </child component2> 
 <child component3 *ngIf='c1 === 3' (click)='c1 = 4'> </child component3>
 <child component4 *ngIf='c1 === 4' (click)='c1 = 1'> </child component4>
<parent component>
```

// In TS:

```
c1 = 1;
```